# Give a bijection from $\Bbb N\to\omega^{\omega}$ based upon counting consecutive similar digits of binary strings

Tags: functions, set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

**Question**

Give a bijection from $\omega^{\omega}\to\Bbb N$ based upon counting consecutive similar digits of binary strings:  There is a near-bijection given in attempt 1 below; the aim is to fix it to give a bijection with near order-isomorphism to the original function.

$\omega^{\omega}$ is the set of ordinals expressible in Cantor normal form as:

$$\sum_{i=k}^0\omega^i\cdot a_i:a_i\in\Bbb N_{\geq0}$$

**Step 1**

A near-bijection is to let $a_i$  count the number of consecutive ones and twos in an integer's binary representation:

$27=11011_2\mapsto\omega^2\cdot2+\omega+2$

But since there are no zero-length sequences of ones or twos in binary representations, this is unable to represent any ordinal having a finitely long sequence of consecutive zero coefficients.  For example $\omega^2+2$ has no binary string representation.

**Step 2**

One can then reduce each coefficient by $1$ like this:

$27=11011_2\mapsto\omega^2+1$

This now represents zero coefficients, but it fails to inject because it gives the same ordinal $0$ for all the following numbers:

$S_n=1,2,5,10,21,42,85,\ldots$.

**Attempt**

The task is to fix this approach with a near order-isomorphism.  I'm not sure how to proceed but I have a rough hunch we might be able to add or multiply a number (which may not truly be an ordinal) of the following form or similar:

$$\beta=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\omega^{2i+k}\cdot$$

Also, perhaps we can count up the number of $S_n$ having a representation shorter than any given integer and increase the ordinal by that many.  But I'm unclear precisely how to complete the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you insist on talking about ordinals when [Noah told you it is nothing more than an unnecessary distraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3811013), since a bijection from naturals to finite sequences of naturals will do. Here is one bijection based on the binary representation and blocks of consecutive similar digits:

- Map $0$ to $⟨⟩$.
- For each positive natural $n$, write down the binary representation of $n$, and split it into blocks each of which starts with a "$1$" and has only "$0$"s after that, and count the number of zeroes in each block, and map $n$ to that sequence of counts. For example, $1101_2$ is mapped to $⟨0,1,0⟩$.

Note that every positive natural is mapped to a unique non-empty tuple, and that every non-empty tuple is mapped to from some positive natural.

To biject from finite sequences to finite sequences where the first term (if any) is non-zero, simply add one to that first term.

Alternatively (as said in comments), to biject from naturals to $ω^ω$, pad the binary representation with infinitely many zeroes to its left, and map it to the finite sum $\sum_{k=0}^∞ ω^k·a_k$ where $a_k$ is the number of ones after the $(k+1)$-th rightmost zero but before the $k$-th rightmost zero (or the rightmost end if $k=0$). This also handles $0$ correctly. Obviously, you can also compute the mapping without doing the padding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can take or leave the ordinal representation but on balance for me it adds none of the mystery Noah was referring to, and it opens up more compact and descriptive language such as $\omega\cdot\alpha+\beta$ rather than having to write about appending coefficients before or after. To get the bijection to $\omega^\omega$, how do I deal with the leading zero (to the left) otherwise I would have $⟨0,1,0⟩\cong ⟨1,0⟩$?

Comment: @samerivertwice: To biject from finite sequences to finite sequences where the first term is non-zero, simply add one to that first term. Obviously, don't change the empty sequence. As for your claim of so-called 'compact and descriptive language', that is simply false.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it.  If you finish up the bijection to $\omega^\omega$ I can accept your excellent answer.

Comment: I'm forming the view that if you split the binary string (including $\overline0$) into substrings starting with a $0$ and counting the consecutive $1$s after each $0$, then you get the bijection without having to increment the leftmost term, does that look right? It even writes the $\sum_{n=k}^\infty\omega^k\cdot0$ part too.

Comment: @samerivertwice: Yes reading the binary string backwards after adding infinitely many zeros does give you what you want.